# Switch function in Python

Tags: python

I wrote this `switch` function for Python, as there isn't a built-in one and most of the Googlable ones doesn't execute code, but only `return` something (I admit I haven't looked much further than a single Stack Oveflow page to see what people use, but a lot of the solutions are unnecessarily complex):

```
def switch(variable, **cases):
    for case in cases.keys():
       if variable is case:
           exec(cases[case])
```

I use `**cases`, due to this syntax:

```
def switch(variable, **cases):
    for case in cases.keys():
       if variable is case:
           exec(cases[case])

some_string = "a"
switch(some_string,
       b="print('It is b!')",
       a="print('It is a!')")

some_string = "b"
switch(some_string,
       b="print('It is b!')",
       a="print('It is a!')")

some_string = "c"
switch(some_string,
       b="print('It is b!')",
       a="print('It is a!')")
```

Can this be optimized/made more pythonic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it works for small strings in CPython, `"foobar" is "foobar"` is not guaranteed to be true. `"foobar" == "foobar"`, however is. This is due to the fact that `is` compares memory addresses, while `==` compares content.

Also, for iterating simultaneously over the keys and values of a dictionary `dict.items()` (`dict.iteritems()` in Python 2.x) is recommended.

With these two changes your code would become:

```
def switch(variable, **cases):
    for case, val in cases.items():
        if variable == case:
            exec(val)
```

Comment: I use `is` to prevent things like`1 == True`. I agree that iterating simultaneously over the keys and values is more Pythonic, though.

Comment: @Shifterovich But it does not make sense to have a switch with different cases for `True` and `1` as they are equal in Python. The code with `is` can break unexpectedly, anytime.

Comment: This depends on the developer's way of writing code. I never interchange `1` and `True`. In some cases, it's important to differentiate these two.

Comment: To prevent both of these issues, you can compare the `type` of the values when comparing their value.

Comment: `if type(variable) == type(case) and variable == case`

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich That would be kind of **inconsistent** :)

Comment: Why/how would that be **inconsistent**?

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich What is the point of trying to prevent `1 == True` when using the `**kwargs` syntax? All your keys are guaranteed to be strings...

Comment: @MathiasEttinger That's a very good point. I thought this works for `'1' == True`, `'True' == True`, etc. Thanks. Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 6):

The most Pythonic way to do is to define a (reusable) dictionary. Most often this dictionary contains callables, but not necessarily.

The least efficient way to do it, though, is to loop over each possibility as you do. It computes in \$O(n)\$ rather than \$O(1)\$ as a dictionnary can offer. And avoid the capability of short-circuit a succession of `if...elif...elif...else` can offer.

So, at the very least, use something like

```
def switch(value, **cases):
    try:
        statement = cases[value]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        exec(statement)
```

However, I find that defining the various statements at each call is innefficient. As I said, it's better to be able to define a reusable dictionary. I would also advise against the use of `exec` and make the function more generic; letting the user decide what to do with the retrived value:

```
def switch(value, cases, default=None):
    try:
        return cases[value]
    except KeyError:
        return default
```

Usage being:

```
PRINT_STUFF = {
    'a': lambda: print("It's a!"),
    'b': lambda: print("It's b!"),
}

switch('a', PRINT_STUFF, lambda: None)()
switch('b', PRINT_STUFF, lambda: None)()
switch('c', PRINT_STUFF, lambda: None)()
```

But way... This `try..except` reminds me of something... Oh the `dict.get` method. So there is really no need for `switch`:

```
PRINT_STUFF.get('a', lambda: None)()
PRINT_STUFF.get('b', lambda: None)()
PRINT_STUFF.get('c', lambda: None)()
```

Or, if you trully insist on using strings rather than real callable objects:

```
PRINT_STUFF = {
    'a': 'print("It\'s a!")',
    'b': 'print("It\'s b!")',
}

exec(PRINT_STUFF.get('a', 'pass'))
exec(PRINT_STUFF.get('b', 'pass'))
exec(PRINT_STUFF.get('c', 'pass'))
```